# Совет по автоматизации обновления сертификата от Let's Encrypt на сайте с хостингом от NIC

Tags: python-3.x, bash, letsencrypt, certbot

коллеги!
Появилась потребность автоматического обновления сертификата от Let's Encrypt на сайте с хостингом от NIC.
Хотел посоветоваться с Вами, каким образом проще и эффективнее это сделать.
Была мысль использовать certbot, но , как я понял, он используется на веб серверах. А у нас веб-хостинг.
Также думал использовать питон, который каждые 3 месяца будет ставить крон на обновление сертификата на сайте, но нашёл только как им проверить сертификат на актуальность. Как его обновить не нашёл(
Буду рад любым советам!
Спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автоматическое обновление сертификатов letsencrypt на сайтах NIC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215769/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-letsencrypt-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-nic)

Comment: пожалуйста, не надо плодить дубликаты вопросов. лучше было исправить текущий. а сейчас, раз уж создали новую версию, удалите эту, пожалуйста: у вас, как автора, должна быть доступна такая возможность (ссылка «удалить» ниже текста вопроса).