# Автоматическое обновление сертификатов letsencrypt на сайтах NIC

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, cron, letsencrypt, certbot

Появилась потребность автоматического обновления сертификата от **Let's Encrypt** на сайте с хостингом от **NIC**. Хотел посоветоваться с Вами, каким образом проще и эффективнее это сделать. Была мысль использовать **certbot**, но , как я понял, он используется на веб серверах. А у нас веб-хостинг. Также думал использовать **питон**, который каждые 3 месяца будет ставить **крон** на обновление сертификата на сайте, но нашёл только как им проверить сертификат на актуальность. Как его обновить не нашёл(
Буду рад любым советам! Спасибо!

Comment: Хо́стинг — **услуга** по предоставлению ресурсов **для размещения** информации **на сервере**, постоянно имеющем доступ к сети.

Comment: Если хостинг NIC не предоставляет такой возможности официально, то или никак, или очень много страдать с реверс-инжинирингом его внутренних API

Comment: можно завернуть в cloudflare, там используется Let's Encrypt Authority X3

Comment: Скажите, а как вы его туда поставили? Они же только за деньги сертификаты ставят.